# How to get a specific text slice in string

Tags: python

I'm trying to work with Instagram

So, say I have a link https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn4Lmo_j0Jc/

And I want to get a `Bn4Lmo_j0jc` only. I could just remove everthing before this ID and the last `/`

But what if my link looks like this:
https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn4Lmo_j0Jc/?taken-by=instagram or this https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn1GpYyBFSl/?hl=en&taken-by=zaralarsson so there is no exact number of characters I need to remove. What will be the easiest way to solve this?

Comment: You may want to consider perusing a basic tutorial, which SO is not.

Comment: does the set of values always follow `/p/` if so you could use that as a indicator to find the values using `re` or splitting the url

Answer (score 2):

how about this?

```
import urllib

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn4Lmo_j0Jc/'

parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)

parts.path
'/p/Bn4Lmo_j0Jc/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = link.split("/")
lst[-1] if not lst[-1].startswith("?") and lst[-1] else lst[-2]
```

where `link` is your link string.

(The result is the last element in `lst`, if it *doesn't start with `?` and is not empty* - else the result is the last but one element.)

Comment: You code does not give output for `'https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn4Lmo_j0Jc/'`

Comment: Thanks, @mad_, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Consistent Format

Given that you will always have a URL https://instagram.com/p/, all you would need is to use a string interpreter.

```
base_url = 'https://instagram.com/p/' 
main = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn4Lmo_j0Jc/?taken-by=instagram'
# remove your base url
# split on separator '/'
# select the ID in index [0]
main.replace(base_url,'').split('/')[0]
'Bn4Lmo_j0Jc'
```

#### For Looping

If you have a list of URLs that you want to extract and capture:

```
url_base = 'https://instagram.com/p/' 
url_list = [url1,url2,url3]
id_list = []

for url in url_list:   
   id_list.append(url.replace(url_base,'').split('/')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib import parse
def getId(url):
    return parse.urlparse(url).path[3:-1]

print(getId('https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn1GpYyBFSl/?hl=en&taken-by=zaralarsson'))
print(getId('https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn4Lmo_j0Jc/'))
print(getId('https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn4Lmo_j0Jc/?taken-by=instagram'))
```

Output :

```
Bn1GpYyBFSl
Bn4Lmo_j0Jc
Bn4Lmo_j0Jc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex here. It can also deal with if your url has multiple /p/ after ID field in which you are concerned

```
import re
a=['https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn1GpYyBFSl/?hl=en&taken-by=zaralarsson',
'https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn4Lmo_j0Jc/',
'https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn4Lmo_j0Jc/?taken-by=instagram/p/12321']
[re.findall('/p/(\w{1,})',i)[0] for i in a]
```